# What is the limit of a function composed of two functions where one has a limit and the other does not?

Tags: limits

can one conclude a rule for a case where a function is a composite function of two added terms?

Take for instance:

$\lim_{(x,y)\longrightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}+cos(xy)$

This function is composed of two terms, where the first on the right, does not have a limit and the cosine terms has the limit 1. What is the limit of the whole function then? Assuming it does not exist, is it because one can *always* conclude that the non-existing limit overrules the existence of a limit for a summation of limits?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$g(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}+\cos(xy)$$ and suppose $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}$ exits.  Then  $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} g(x,y)-\cos(xy)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$ also exists, and we know this isn't true.

So, if you have two functions, one that has a limit at the point in question, and the other that hasn't, then the sum or difference of the functions wont have a limit at that point.  This isn't true of the product, though.  Consider $x\sin\frac1x$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $f, g$ are two functions, say from $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and $f$ has a limit as $x \to x_0$ but $g$ does not have a limit as $x \to x_0$, then $f+g$ does not have a limit as $x \to x_0$.

**Proof.** Since the limit of $g$ at $x_0$ does not exist, we may choose sequences $(x_n)_n$ and $(x_n')_n$ both tending to $x_0$ such that $M = \lim_n g(x_n) \neq \lim_n g(x_n') = M'$. Since $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exists, call it $L$, we have $\lim_n f(x_n) = \lim_n f(x'_n) = L$. Thus
$$
\lim_n (f(x_n) + g(x_n)) = L + M,
$$
$$
\lim_n (f(x'_n) + g(x'_n)) = L + M',
$$
and since $L+M \neq L + M'$, we conclude that $f+g$ does not have a limit as $x \to x_0$.

*Warning*: It is possible that if neither $f,g$ has a limit, $f+g$ can still have one, e.g. take $f = -g$.

*Note*: I am assuming "limit exists" means it exists in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanations! Can one use the fact where one places (x,x) instead of (x,y) in the limit, generate that limit, and compared it with the limit where one places (x, x^2) for (x,y) in the limit. If these are not equal, then there is no limit?

Comment: Yes, in general, if you can find two sequences/curves/paths, approaching a point along which a function approaches two different values, or a single sequence/curve/path approaching a point along which it does not approach a value, then the overall limit in $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not exists.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!